# How do we specify the direction of current flow?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

Here are two different circuits but with the same components; the diodes are real, they have an internal resistance and a voltage V_d, I don’t know what's the factor that decides how do we orient the current flow i's direction:

[image]

Comment: What makes you ask - is this a homework question?

Comment: @TonyM its an example from my textbook it has a solution but i dont understand the way they setup the current flow

Answer (score 3):

When a diode is conducting in the forward direction, conventional current flows in the direction of the 'arrow' in the diode symbol.

But you can analyze a circuit with the current direction picked arbitrarily (maybe you don't know the direction yet), if you get it wrong then the sign will be negative. No big deal.

Comment: well it would be a big deal because i will get the wrong graph of V_s

Comment: If it represents reality it's not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In figure 3 there is no current flow.
The voltage source (battery) is positive at the top and negative at the bottom, the current flows from + to -!

But in figure 3 the current flow through the diode is in the opposite to the technical current flow.

I remember it this way: This diode looks like an arrow and it is open for this direction. If the current want to flow from the other direction, there is this line what stops it.

Comment: why in figure 2 the flow is opposite to figure 3?

Comment: If you look into the datasheet of diodes (planar-epitaxial like the 1N4148 or Schottky-diode like the 1N5819) then you see the maximum positive current flow, but there is a very small negative current flow too. The current flow over Schottky diodes can be pretty high, around 1mA or more is possible.